# Microsoft Bing Translator- "Alternative meanings/translations"

Tags: microsoft-translator, bing-translator-api

When you go to translate.bing.com and enter a word, you get a long list of alternative translations on the right side, which is fabulous. In case of, say, 允许, it looks like -[允许 meanings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op7P3.png)  which, with the scores is very right from my knowledge of Chinese. However, if you do the same using the API- you get a single result- "Admit" with rating 5 and matchDegree 100.

Does anybody know what's happening here? I asked on the Microsoft translator forum but was told that the "alternative translations" API is unrelated to the meanings on the right side. So my question is how does one get those meanings on the right side?

My API query uses the `GetTranslationsArrayRequest` as follows:

```
    <GetTranslationsArrayRequest>
        <AppId/>
        <From>zh-CHS</From>
        <Options>
            <Category xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2">general</Category>
            <ContentType xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2">text/plain</ContentType>
            <ReservedFlags xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2"/>
            <State xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2"/>
            <Uri xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2"/>
            <User xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2"/>
        </Options>
        <Texts>
            <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">允许</string>
        </Texts>
        <To>en</To>
        <MaxTranslations>10</MaxTranslations>
    </GetTranslationsArrayRequest>
```